# AzureCognitiveSearch Index : QPS for the azure search service showing low in azure portal

Tags: azure, performance, query-optimization, azure-cognitive-search

I am working on Azure Cognitive Search.I have noticed the following issue reg Index performance.

- Azure Cognitive Search Service - QPS (Queries per second) is showing low in the portal.
  we are getting qps # 2 , for tier - Standard S1 , 3p*3r =>9 search units.Index size =7 GB, no.of documents =7 millions.

Note: we are using custom analyzer for 3 columns and default analyzer for the rest of the columns.(Total Index Columns - 20)

Any thoughts for improving the performance would be appreciated!

Thanks
Bhanu

-created an index with 7 million documents/7.33 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Queries per second refer to the number of search queries your system receives. It is unclear if you submit more than 2 queries per second to the system. If you run a performance test and gradually scale up the query rate, your will get a number that reflects what your system is able to deliver.

Once you hit the limit, you will see queries being throttled in the monitor section of the Azure Portal.

Comment: Thanks Dan, for the response. We are uploading 20K records to the API connected to Azuresearch Index. We tried testing with 40K/60K also, but could not see rise in qps. Can you please provide details, how to scale up query rate. I have checked the throttling queries in azure search service metrics and it is showing up 0% always.

Comment: Uploading records will not affect the QPS. The QPS is an abbreviation for Queries Per Second. When you upload records, you are not querying. 

When you or an end user searches for something, it will count as a query. If your throttling says 0% it makes sense, because you are not QUERYing, you are indexing.